# How to calculate mask using java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this code. Here the map is `Map<Data, Boolean>`

```
int mask = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Data, Boolean> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getKey().getValue() > 0 && entry.getValue()) {
    mask = mask | (1 << (entry.getKey().getValue() - 1));
  }
}
```

I want to calculate mask using Java stream. Here I tried to but only get then filter list. Don't know how calculate the mask here.

```
Integer mask = map.entrySet().filter( entry -> entry.getKey().getValue() > 0 && entry.getValue()).?
```

Comment: Writing a function for the above code since `mask` is mutating might look ugly. You are better off with imperative code IMO.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Can you explain a bit ?  I don't understand your point. Do you think my current solution is fine ?

Comment: `map.entrySet().filter( entry -> entry.getKey().getValue() > 0 && entry.getValue()).forEach(k->{mask=mask | (1 << (k.getKey().getValue() - 1))});`

Comment: @Daemon This will emit a compiler error: `mask` must be final or effectively final.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can map your entry to the calculated value and then apply the `or` within a reduce operator:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
       .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() && entry.getKey().getValue() > 0)
       .mapToInt(entry -> (1 << (entry.getKey().getValue() - 1)))
       .reduce(0, (r, i) -> r | i)
```

Edit: Added 0 as identity element to the reduce operation to have a default value of 0 if the map is empty.

Edit2: As suggested in the comments I reversed the filter order to avoid unnecessary method calls

Edit3: As suggested in the comments `mapToInt` is now used

Comment: Nice solution.  This is trivial but I would reverse the filter to first check for a boolean.  Then you avoid a double method lookup unless the boolean is true.

Comment: Mind the existence of `mapToInt`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this , but as Aniket said above here `mask` is mutating not a good idea to use Strem.

```
map.entrySet().filter( entry -> entry.getKey().getValue() > 0 && entry.getValue()).forEach(k->{mask=mask | (1 << (k.getKey().getValue() - 1))});
```

Comment: is it compile?  mask outside and should be final.

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another alternative.

```
int mask = map.entrySet().stream().filter(Entry::getValue)
            .mapToInt(e -> e.getKey().getValue()).filter(a -> a > 0)
            .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a | (1<<(b-1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62409825/11733759) but here reduce is written in other way indicated that it should start from 0.

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().getValue() > 0 && entry.getValue())
    .map(entry -> (1 << (entry.getKey().getValue() - 1)))
    .reduce(0, (a, v) -> a | v);
```

As it was maintained in comments you can do further decomposition it in this way:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .map(entry -> entry.getKey().getValue())
    .filter(keyValue -> keyValue > 0)
    .map(keyValue -> (1 << (keyValue - 1)))
    .reduce(0, (a, v) -> a | v);
```

Comment: Like the other answer, it will benefit from using `mapToInt`, especially the second variant, as most operations can be done without boxing overhead.